# how to assign a same variable value to be changed dynamically

Tags: swift

var myFloatValue = 10

myFloatValue:Double = Double(myFloatValue)

println ("My value is (myFloatValue)")

how to assign a same variable and value to be changed dynamically. Plz tell me the Solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myFloatValue = 10 // here you are omitting myFloatValue type so Swift will define it as Integer


myFloatValue:Double = Double(myFloatValue)  // after you create your var you can change its value but not its type.
```

you should declare it like this:

```
var myFloatValue = 10.0
```

or like this

```
var myFloatValue:Double = 10
```

if you would like myFloatValue value to be changed just do like this:

```
var myFloatValue:Double = 10
println(myFloatValue) // 10.0

myFloatValue = 20
println(myFloatValue) // now myFloatValue = 20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift is a strongly typed language, and types are resolved at compilation time - they never change at runtime. So if you declare a variable as `Float`, you cannot change it to a different type later.

Also, Swift is also so strongly typed that it doesn't support implicit conversion of compatible types, for example you cannot assign an `Int16` to an `Int32` without an explicit conversion.